# Mocking Logger and LoggerFactory with PowerMock and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, slf4j, powermock

I have the following Logger I want to mock out, but to validate log entries are getting called, not for the content.

```
private static Logger logger = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoodbyeController.class);
```

I want to Mock ANY class that is used for LoggerFactory.getLogger() but I could not find out how to do that.
This is what I ended up with so far:

```
@Before
public void performBeforeEachTest() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
    when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoodbyeController.class)).
        thenReturn(loggerMock);

    when(loggerMock.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
    doNothing().when(loggerMock).error(any(String.class));

    ...
}
```

I would like to know:

1. Can I Mock the static `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` to work for any class?
2. I can only seem to run `when(loggerMock.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);` in the `@Before` and thus I cannot seem to change the characteristics per method. Is there a way around this?

---

**Edit findings:**

I thought I tried this already and it didnt work:

```
 when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(loggerMock);
```

But thank you, as it did work.

However I have tried countless variations to:

```
when(loggerMock.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
```

I cannot get the loggerMock to change its behavior outside of `@Before` but this only happens with Coburtura. With Clover, the coverage shows 100% but there is still an issue either way.

I have this simple class:

```
public ExampleService{
    private static final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleService.class);

    public String getMessage() {        
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("isDebugEnabled");
        logger.debug("isDebugEnabled");
    }
    return "Hello world!";
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I have this test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFactory.class})
public class ExampleServiceTests {

    @Mock
    private Logger loggerMock;
    private ExampleServiceservice = new ExampleService();

    @Before
    public void performBeforeEachTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).
            thenReturn(loggerMock);

        //PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // fails
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsDebugEnabled_True() throws Exception {
        when(loggerMock.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
        doNothing().when(loggerMock).debug(any(String.class));

        assertThat(service.getMessage(), is("Hello null: 0"));
        //verify(loggerMock, atLeast(1)).isDebugEnabled(); // fails
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsDebugEnabled_False() throws Exception {
        when(loggerMock.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(false);
        doNothing().when(loggerMock).debug(any(String.class));

        assertThat(service.getMessage(), is("Hello null: 0"));
        //verify(loggerMock, atLeast(1)).isDebugEnabled(); // fails
    }
}
```

In clover I show 100% coverage of the `if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){` block.
But if I try to verify the `loggerMock`:

```
verify(loggerMock, atLeast(1)).isDebugEnabled();
```

I get zero interactions.
I also tried `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()`; in `@Before` but that also has zero interactions.

This just seems strange that Cobertura shows the `if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){` as being not 100% complete, and Clover does, but both agree the verification fails.

Comment: Have you tried the @MockPolicy? [Examples here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPolicies) are for EasyMock style mocks but can be adapted for Mockito.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

EDIT 2020-09-21: Since 3.4.0, Mockito supports mocking static methods, API is still incubating and is likely to change, in particular around stubbing and verification. It requires the `mockito-inline` artifact. And you don't need to prepare the test or use any specific runner. All you need to do is :

```
@Test
public void name() {
    try (MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> integerMock = mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class)) {
        final Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        integerMock.when(() -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);
        new Controller().log();
        verify(logger).warn(any());
    }
}
```

The two inportant aspect in this code, is that you need to scope when the static mock applies, i.e. within this try block. And you need to call the stubbing and verification api from the `MockedStatic` object.

---

@Mick, try to prepare the owner of the static field too, eg :

```
@PrepareForTest({GoodbyeController.class, LoggerFactory.class})
```

EDIT1 : I just crafted a small example. First the controller :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Controller {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

    public void log() { logger.warn("yup"); }
}
```

Then the test :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Controller.class, LoggerFactory.class})
public class ControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);
        
        new Controller().log();
        
        verify(logger).warn(anyString());
    }
}
```

Note the imports !
Noteworthy libs in the classpath : Mockito, PowerMock, JUnit, logback-core, logback-clasic, slf4j

---

EDIT2 : As it seems to be a popular question, I'd like to point out that **if these log messages are that important** and require to be tested, i.e. they are feature / business part of the system **then introducing a real dependency that make clear theses logs are features would be a so much better in the whole system design**, instead of relying on static code of a standard and technical classes of a logger.

For this matter I would recommend to craft something like= a `Reporter` class with methods such as `reportIncorrectUseOfYAndZForActionX` or `reportProgressStartedForActionX`. This would have the benefit of making the feature visible for anyone reading the code. But it will also help to achieve tests, change the implementations details of this particular feature.

Hence you wouldn't need static mocking tools like PowerMock. **In my opinion static code can be fine, but as soon as the test demands to verify or to mock static behavior it is necessary to refactor and introduce clear dependencies.**

Comment: NOTE: If you tried a second @ Test in there, you'll have a problem. verify() won't work when called again in an additional test. Not if you use @ Before, or new var names. The classLoader's only going to make one of them, so you can't have two different static classes. Break your tests out into individual classes.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't get it work... Mockito says.. Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Works fine for me (including verification).  Make sure you are using @PrepareForTest and also verify that you've mocked the right log lookup method of the log factory.

Comment: +1 for the mention "introducing a real dependency that make clear these logs are features would be a so much better in the whole system design"

Comment: @Brice I know this is quite an old question, but I'd like to ask you something regarding your advice of "introducing a real dependency" and avoiding the need of static mocking tools. I quite agree with your point about making the feature visible for anyone, however, I think that if you need to unit test that reporting class also, you'll still need to use these static mocking tools. Won't you?

Comment: @beni0888 Indeed it is advised to unit test this class, but the concrete dependency can be designed with a `Logger` field set in the constructor(s), and as such it would be possible to pass a pure mockito `Logger` mock, in some constructor that is visible for testing purpose only.

Comment: Wish I read the EDIT2 about ditching static fields before I jumped to implementing the first code snippet.

Answer (score 22):

Somewhat late to the party - I was doing something similar and needed some pointers and ended up here. Taking no credit - I took all of the code from Brice but got the "zero interactions" than Cengiz got.

Using guidance from what jheriks amd Joseph Lust had put I think I know why - I had my object under test as a field and newed it up in a @Before unlike Brice. Then the actual logger was not the mock but a real class init'd as jhriks suggested...

I would normally do this for my object under test so as to get a fresh object for each test. When I moved the field to a local and newed it in the test it ran ok. However, if I tried a second test it was not the mock in my test but the mock from the first test and I got the zero interactions again.

When I put the creation of the mock in the @BeforeClass the logger in the object under test is always the mock but see the note below for the problems with this...

**Class under test**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClassWithSomeLogging  {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClassWithSomeLogging.class);

    public void doStuff(boolean b) {
        if(b) {
            LOG.info("true");
        } else {
            LOG.info("false");
        }

    }
}
```

**Test**

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFactory.class})
public class MyClassWithSomeLoggingTest {

    private static Logger mockLOG;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        mockLOG = mock(Logger.class);
        when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(mockLOG);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        MyClassWithSomeLogging myClassWithSomeLogging = new MyClassWithSomeLogging();
        myClassWithSomeLogging.doStuff(true);

        verify(mockLOG, times(1)).info("true");
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt2() {
        MyClassWithSomeLogging myClassWithSomeLogging = new MyClassWithSomeLogging();
        myClassWithSomeLogging.doStuff(false);

        verify(mockLOG, times(1)).info("false");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void verifyStatic() {
        verify(mockLOG, times(1)).info("true");
        verify(mockLOG, times(1)).info("false");
        verify(mockLOG, times(2)).info(anyString());
    }
}
```

**Note**

If you have two tests with the same expectation I had to do the verify in the @AfterClass as the invocations on the static are stacked up - `verify(mockLOG, times(2)).info("true");`  - rather than times(1) in each test as the second test would fail saying there where 2 invocation of this. This is pretty pants but I couldn't find a way to clear the invocations. I'd like to know if anyone can think of a way round this....

Comment: Markus Wendl's suggestion to use reset worked for me.

Comment: +500. @BeforeClass made the difference for me.

Answer (score 6):

In answer to your first question, it should be as simple as replacing:

```
   when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoodbyeController.class)).thenReturn(loggerMock);
```

with

```
   when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(loggerMock);
```

Regarding your second question (and possibly the puzzling behavior with the first), I think the problem is that logger is static.  So,

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoodbyeController.class);
```

is executed when the *class* is initialized, not the when the *object* is instantiated.  Sometimes this can be at about the same time, so you'll be OK, but it's hard to guarantee that.  So you set up LoggerFactory.getLogger to return your mock, but the logger variable may have already been set with a real Logger object by the time your mocks are set up.

You may be able to set the logger explicitly using something like [ReflectionTestUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) (I don't know if that works with static fields) or change it from a static field to an instance field.  Either way, you don't need to mock LoggerFactory.getLogger because you'll be directly injecting the mock Logger instance.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeService{
  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SomeService.class);

  public void callSomeMethod(){
   ...
   ...
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(String.format("some message ....."));
    }
  }

}
```

**JUNIT Test Coverages -**

```
import java.io.IOException;
 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
 
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
 

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private Appender mockAppender;
 
  private Logger logger;
 
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    when(mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MockAppender");
    when(mockAppender.isStarted()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockAppender.isStopped()).thenReturn(false);
 
    logger = (Logger)LogManager.getLogger(SomeService.class);
    logger.addAppender(mockAppender);
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
  }
 
  
 
  @Test
  public void callSomeMethodTest() {
    //write test cases, logger.isDebugEnabled() will call.
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can reset the invocations using Mockito.reset(mockLog). You should call this before every test, so inside @Before would be a good place.

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit injection.
No other approach will allow you  for instance to run tests in parallel in the same JVM.

Patterns that use anything classloader wide like static log binder or messing with environmental thinks like logback.XML are bust when it comes to testing.

Consider the parallelized tests I mention , or consider the case where you want to intercept logging of component A whose construction is hidden behind api B. This latter case is easy to deal with if you are using a dependency injected loggerfactory from the top, but not if you inject Logger as there no seam in this assembly at ILoggerFactory.getLogger.

And its not all about unit testing either. Sometimes we want integration tests to emit logging. Sometimes we don't. Someone's we want some of the integration testing logging to be selectively suppressed, eg for expected errors that would otherwise clutter the CI console and confuse. All easy if you inject ILoggerFactory from the top of your mainline (or whatever di framework you might use)

So...

Either inject a reporter as suggested or adopt a pattern of injecting the ILoggerFactory. By explicit  ILoggerFactory injection rather than Logger you can support many access/intercept patterns and parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a test class that mocks private static final Logger named `log` in class `LogUtil`.

In addition to mocking the `getLogger` factory call, it is necessary to explicitly set the field using reflection, in `@BeforeClass`

```
public class LogUtilTest {

    private static Logger logger;

    private static MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> loggerFactoryMockedStatic;

    /**
     * Since {@link LogUtil#log} being a static final variable it is only initialized once at the class load time
     * So assertions are also performed against the same mock {@link LogUtilTest#logger}
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        logger = mock(Logger.class);
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic = mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic.when(() -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(anyString())).thenReturn(logger);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(LogUtil.class, "log", logger);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after() {
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would you need to mock the static method if you overwrite the return value of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working without `PowerMock` with `Mockito` only for one test. When I have two tests with `verify`, the second started to fail with `no interactions with this mock` when I run all tests in the class. Separately both tests worked.

After some experiments it worked for me only when I make my mock logger `static`.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    private static MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> loggerFactoryMockedStatic;
    private static final Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeAll() {
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic = mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic.when(() -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceUnderTest.class))
                .thenReturn(logger);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterAll() {
        loggerFactoryMockedStatic.close();
    }


    @Before
    public void init() {
        Mockito.reset(logger); // important as it's static
        // ...

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        // ...
        verifyNoInteractions(logger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution using Whitebox :

```
@Test
void getMessage() {
    Whitebox.setInternalState(AeAuthTokenOidcMapper.class, "logger", logger);
    when(logger.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(true);

    String mes = sut.getMessage();

    assertEquals("hi", mes);
    verify(logger).debug("message");
}
```

[image]